# Python - How can i get decimal value from text file name

Tags: python, file, extract

Hello I have this method.
How can i get the value of 3.34 and 9.1 from my File Name??? cant seem to extract decimal value out. Please help! thanks in advance.
For Example my FileName is called.
123 3.34 9.1 IP

## File extracted from desktop FILENAME: **123 3.34 9.1 IP**

```
def extractFilename(FileName):
    Text = string.split(FileName, " ")
    Name = stripText[0]
    Thickness = stripText[1]
    SurfaceArea = stripText[2]
    Type = stripText[len(stripText)-1]
    return (Name,Thickness,SurfaceArea, Type)
    pass
```

Comment: What is `FileNameOnly` and `stripText`? And why put `pass` after the `return` statement? Did you even run this code yet?

Comment: Yes i did run the program and it works well. Just that it wont take in decimal point

Comment: why are you using string.split()? FileName.split(...) is what you want.

Comment: anw what parameter must i put in the split(...)

Comment: still can't. It can't take in decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    import math
    def is_number(s):
       try:
           float(s)
           return True
       except ValueError:
           return False
    filename = "123 3.34 9.91 p"
    val = filename.split(" ")
    for items in val:
       if is_number(items):
           if float(items) != math.floor(float(items)):
               print items
```

Working:- 
First it splits the filname. After iterating over each element it checks whether the item is a string or not. If it's not a string, it checks whether the integeral part is equal to the number. If it's equal its a integer otherwise it's a float.

Comment: The code is working perfectly, on my system. Can you point out the exact line on which there is an error, and also what is the error there?